# Autocorrelation and var-cov matrix

Tags: regression, economics, correlation, least-squares, covariance

$$Y_t=\beta_1+\beta_2 X_{t2}+\dots +\beta_k X_{tk}+\epsilon_t \qquad (t=1,\dots,T)$$
$$\epsilon_t=\rho \epsilon_{t-1}+v_t, \qquad v_t \sim \mathrm{i.i.d.}(0,\sigma^2_v)$$

GLS estimation under AR(1) errors:
$Y=X\beta +\epsilon$, $\epsilon \sim (0,\Phi)$
$$\Phi=\frac{\sigma^2_v}{1-\rho^2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &\rho&\rho^2&\dots&\rho^{T-1}\\ \rho&1&\rho&\dots\\ \dots \\ \rho^{T-1}&\dots\ & \dots & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix} =\sigma^2_\epsilon \Psi$$
$$\hat\beta_{GLS}=(X' \Psi^{-1}X)^{-1}X'\Psi^{-1}Y$$

The book says "transform and apply OLS",
$$P'P=\Psi^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &-\rho&0&\dots&0\\ -\rho&1+\rho^2&-\rho&\dots\\ \dots \\ 0&\dots\ & \dots & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $$P=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{1-\rho^2} &0&0&\dots&0\\ -\rho&1&0&\dots\\ \dots \\ 0&\dots\ & \dots & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

However I can't follow that process.
How can I get $P'P$ and $P$?

Comment: You don't need to "transform", whatever that means. You already have the formula for $\hat{beta}$. It's only in the derivation for GLS as a "transformed" OLS that you need to know $P$. And $P$ is a square root of the positive definite $\Psi^{-1}$, given by, for example, the spectral theorem.

Comment: @Michael I searched every book and internet pages but they only give the result(I already write above) and do not give any hints  how to derive that. Pleas explain the process of that derivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read you correctly, you're asking two questions:

1. How to get $P$?
2. Once you get $P$, what to do?

Basically you're asking how GLS reduces to OLS.

Answer:

1. Diagonalize the positive definite matrix $\Psi$. You would have diagonalized $f(\Psi)$ for any "reasonable" $f$, in particular $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. This gives you $P = \Psi^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.
2. Now transform your model

$$
PY = PX \beta + P \epsilon.
$$

The transformed error terms $P \epsilon$ are now spherical. So the transformed model satisfies the usual linear model assumption under which OLS is suitable. The OLS formula then gives you

$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^T P^T P X)^{-1} X^T P^T P Y =  (X^T \Psi^{-1} X)^{-1} X^T \Psi^{-1} Y.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can regress $Py$ on $PX$ if you know $\rho$. If you had only a constant and a single explanatory variable, your data would look like this:

$$Py=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}y_1 \\ y_2 - \rho y_1 \\ ... \\y_T-\rho y_{T-1}\end{bmatrix},PX=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{1-\rho^2} & \sqrt{1-\rho^2}x_1 \\ 1- \rho & x_2 - \rho x_1 \\ ... & ...\\1-\rho & x_T-\rho x_{T-1} \end{bmatrix},$$

In the olden days, before nonlinear least squares was easy, you would use the [Conchrane-Orcutt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochrane%E2%80%93Orcutt_estimation) or [Prais-Winsten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prais%E2%80%93Winsten_estimation) feasible GLS procedures when you don't know $\rho$.